# Why "*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated Aborted (core dumped) " error is showing in this code?

Tags: c++

I am implementing a simple selection sort code in this way:

```
int* in_sort (int a[], int l)
{
    int i, j, k, m;

    for (i = 0; i < l - 1; i++) {
        m = a[i];
        k = i;
        for (j = i; j < l; j++) {
            if (a[j] < m) {
                k = j;
                m = a[j];
            }
        }
        if (i != k) {
            int t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
        }
    }

    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int a [] = {2, 5, 2, 56, 2, 567, 322, 456, 5, 34};
    int *b = in_sort(a, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) cout << b[i] << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> *** stack smashing detected ***:  terminated Aborted (core dumped)

Why is this happening and how can I solve this? I have watched other answers related to this particular error but can not understand what is wrong in my case.

Comment: `j is 10` outside the loop. a[10] is undefined behaviour

Comment: And your comparison and swap logic is wrong.

Comment: ...and this is not C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's this code:

```
if (i != k) {
    int t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
}
```

You probably meant `a[k]`, not `a[j]` here. `j` will equal `l`, and so `a[j]` is just outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Ah!!! Silly mistake. I haven't seen this kind of error before so I thought maybe I've messed up something when returning the array from the function and didn't notice this minor mistake.